# Python Selenium File Upload -- cannot use os to specify file path

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have encountered a problem uploading a file with selenium, and I'd like to understand why this occurs. I noticed the following:

```
file_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]'))
file_input.send_keys("/absolute/path/to/file.jpeg")
```

That works fine on my machine. However, I need the tests to run in CI, so the path I provide must be dynamic. That's where I've encountered a problem; I am trying to use `os.path.abspath()` to get the absolute path on any system, and it is indeed working to get the absolute path. Printing shows that locally, it gets the exact same path that I use above, but when I do the following, it **does not work**. (By this I mean the no error occurs, but it doesn't seem to even try to upload the file).

```
file_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]'))
file_input.send_keys(os.path.abspath("relative/path/to/file.jpeg"))
```

I have also tried the obvious:

```
file_path=os.path.abspath("relative/path/to/file.jpeg")
print(file_path)
file_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]'))
file_input.send_keys(file_path)
```

Logging `file_path` shows the correct absolute filepath. This also doesn't upload the file, failing silently without an error.

I'm confident I can find a workaround (another way to specify the right absolute path dynamically), but I'd really like to understand: why doesn't this work? I know there is some sort of "magic" done by selenium to upload file, and I haven't seen that code at all, so maybe there is something there? Also python is not my strongest language, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong from that perspective.

Can anyone help me understand why this happens?

Comment: What is relative path to file ?

Comment: I have tried on the current version of both Windows and MacOS. I haven't tried other browsers because I need to test on chrome (version 89). "what is the relative path to the file" -- I'm not sure why that matters, as I have confirmed it returns the exact same absolute filepath as the one I hardcoded, which worked. In any case, I can't share it because the repo is very secured.

Comment: maybe you are missing the filename at the end of the "relative/path/to/file"? I guess the "relative/path/to/file" presents the path to some folder, but not includes the file name and extension.

Comment: @cruisepandey I realize it may be helpful to provide the actual relative path, but unfortunately I can't due to security concerns.

Comment: Where do you that file to be uploaded in your machine ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I'm sorry I don't understand the question, can you clarify maybe?

Comment: The file that you are gonna upload,  where does it resides in your local machine ?

Comment: It's inside the repository which has both the application code and Selenium scripts

Comment: Can you share the sample directory path ? and which os you are using  ?

Comment: @C.Peck Can you add minimal working example? I've tried something similar on Windows, and it's working for me. I have used html from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#example_showing_files_size), then I've done `file_input.send_keys(os.path.abspath('venv\pyvenv.cfg'))` and it is working correctly, file size is checked by html.
The only difference can be if you have in your code `send_keys(<hardcoded>)` and then expect the same from `send_keys(<abspath>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is related to the path variable in `send_keys().` In my testing I was able to use `os.path.abspath("relative/path/to/file.jpeg")`, but this file does not exist.  I would recommending trying something like this, which verifies that the file exist at the path specified.

```
import os

def get_local_path():
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    return current_dir

def get_file_path(filename):
    current_dir = get_local_path()
    current_file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, filename)
    if os.path.exists(current_file_path):
        return current_file_path
    else:
        return ('file path does not exist')

# I don't know the exact local of your file, so you might 
# have to do some testing.
file_to_upload = get_file_path('file.jpeg')

file_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]'))
file_input.send_keys(file_to_upload)
```

I also looked through the source code of `selenium` and I don't see that `send_keys()` will throw an error when something is inputted incorrect.  The browser might display a message when something is entered incorrectly.  When that happens you usually have to extract that error message using `selenium.`. Have you verified that no error messages are being thrown in the browser?

Have you considered validating the `send_key()` input?  Here is a line of code that would help with this.

```
validate_file = file_input.get_attribute('value')
# add code to check to see if the value matches what you sent
```

Comment: Thank you very much, those functions seem to have made it work. Enjoy the bounty!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you with this problem.